# How to create annotated bars colored by group in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, bar-chart

`Matplotlib` is a cross-platform, data visualization and graphical plotting library for Python and is highly customizable.

`Matplotlib` has the great advantage of customization. Below is the customized Histogram with `matploltlib`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

def customized_Histogram(df, j):
    """
    Generate Histogram

    Parameters:
    ****************

    df:
        pandas dataframe

    j(str):
        column name in str

    ****************
    Generates Advanced Histogram
    """

    # Colours for different percentiles
    perc_25_colour = 'gold'
    perc_50_colour = 'mediumaquamarine'
    perc_75_colour = 'deepskyblue'
    perc_95_colour = 'peachpuff'

    # Plot the Histogram from the random data
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))

    # '''
    # counts  = numpy.ndarray of count of data ponts for each bin/column in the histogram
    # bins    = numpy.ndarray of bin edge/range values
    # patches = a list of Patch objects.
    #         each Patch object contains a Rectnagle object. 
    #         e.g. Rectangle(xy=(-2.51953, 0), width=0.501013, height=3, angle=0)
    # '''
    counts, bins, patches = ax.hist(df[j], facecolor=perc_50_colour, edgecolor='gray')


    # Set the ticks to be at the edges of the bins.
    ax.set_xticks(bins.round(2))
    plt.xticks(rotation=70)

    # Set the graph title and axes titles
    plt.title(f'Distribution of {j}', fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=15)
    plt.xlabel(j, fontsize=15)

    # Change the colors of bars at the edges
    twentyfifth, seventyfifth, ninetyfifth = np.percentile(df[j], [25, 75, 95])

    for patch, leftside, rightside in zip(patches, bins[:-1], bins[1:]):

        if rightside < twentyfifth:
            patch.set_facecolor(perc_25_colour)
        elif leftside > ninetyfifth:
            patch.set_facecolor(perc_95_colour)
        elif leftside > seventyfifth:
            patch.set_facecolor(perc_75_colour)

    # Calculate bar centre to display the count of data points and %
    bin_x_centers = 0.5 * np.diff(bins) + bins[:-1]
    bin_y_centers = ax.get_yticks()[1] * 0.25

    # Display the the count of data points and % for each bar in histogram
    for i in range(len(bins)-1):
        bin_label = "{0:,}".format(counts[i]) + "  ({0:,.2f}%)".format((counts[i]/counts.sum())*100)
        plt.text(bin_x_centers[i],
                  bin_y_centers, 
                  bin_label, 
                  rotation=90, 
                  rotation_mode='anchor')

    # Annotation for bar values
    ax.annotate('Each bar shows count and percentage of total',
                xy=(.80,.30), 
                xycoords='figure fraction',
                horizontalalignment='center', 
                verticalalignment='bottom',
                fontsize=10, 
                bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", 
                          fc="white"),
                rotation=-90)

    #create legend
    handles = [Rectangle((0,0),1,1,color=c,ec="k") for c in [
                                                             perc_25_colour, 
                                                             perc_50_colour, 
                                                             perc_75_colour, 
                                                             perc_95_colour
                                                             ]
                ]
    labels= ["0-25 Percentile","25-50 Percentile", "50-75 Percentile", ">95 Percentile"]
    plt.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0., 0.80, 0.99))


    # fig.savefig("filename.jpg",dpi=150, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
```

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

customized_Histogram(tips, "total_bill")
```

**Customized Histogram plot**

[image]

How to plot the above plot using `Plotly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **plotly** can be build customised figures in same way.  Fundamentally it's understanding the API and features (as is case with **matplotlib** solution)
- **matplotlib** `hist()` and **numpy** `histogram()` are fundamentally the same.  Both return *counts* and *bins* https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html
- have then used vectorised logic rather than procedural logic to define color of bars
- **plotly** does not directly have concept of ticks on bar edges.  Have moved *x* value of bar to middle of bins and then defined *xaxis* from bin edges

```
def plotly_histogram(df_in, col):
    col = "total_bill"
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.histogram(df_in[col])).T.rename(columns={0: "count", 1: "edge"})
    # center bars between edges...
    df["x"] = df["edge"] + df["edge"].diff().mode()[0] / 2
    cmap = {
        "0-25 Percentile": "gold",
        "25-50 Percentile": "mediumaquamarine",
        "50-75 Percentile": "deepskyblue",
        ">95 Percentile": "peachpuff",
    }
    df["color"] = np.select(
        [
            df["edge"].shift(s) < np.percentile(df_in[col], p)
            for p, s in zip([25, 50, 95], [-1, 1, 0])
        ],
        list(cmap.keys())[0:3],
        list(cmap.keys())[3],
    )
    df["text"] = df["count"].apply(lambda c: f"{c} ({c/len(df_in)*100:.2f})")
    fig = px.bar(
        df,
        x="x",
        y="count",
        color="color",
        color_discrete_map=cmap,
        hover_data={"x": False, "edge": ":.2f"},
    ).update_layout(
        xaxis={
            "tickmode": "array",
            "tickvals": df["edge"],
            "title": col,
            "tickangle": 285,
            "tickformat": ".2f",
        }
    )

    for r in df.dropna().loc[:, ["x", "text"]].iterrows():
        fig.add_annotation(
            x=r[1]["x"],
            y=0,
            text=r[1]["text"],
            showarrow=False,
            textangle=270,
            yanchor="bottom",
            yshift=10,
        )

    return fig

import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

plotly_histogram(sns.load_dataset("tips"), "total_bill")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to reduce/remove the white space between each bar?

Comment: `bargap=0` as additional parameter in `update_layout()`

Comment: Using `bargap=0` increases the bar width, is there a way to set the bar width??

Comment: Set the width of the figure